# Byte array shows value but the ImgView.Image shows null in ios

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to display an image into `UIImageView` through this method `NSData.FromArray()` but it gives an null reference exception my code is the following:

```
Byte _imgData = GetRawData(_imgPath);  // this method get the byte array of size ([131072]) 
NSData _data = NSData.FromArray(_imgData);
ImgView.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(_data) //in this _data shows the byte array value but the ImgView.Image shows null
```

Byte array get the RLE Compress data.

```
ImgView.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(_data)
```

_data is RLE compress byte data I don't know how I can convert it to IOS supported image format. 
It gives an error, any suggestions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIImage.Load*` methods will return `null` if the data (be it a `NSData` or a filename) is invalid and/or the format is unknown to `UIImage`.

You'll likely need to use a lower level API to provide some data (e.g. width, height, depth) about any *RAW* data. Once that's done you can construct an `UIImage` on top of it.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991067/conversion-of-rle-to-uiimageview-image-in-ios