# Conversion of RLE to UIImageView.Image in IOS

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

How I can convert RLE image data to IOS compatible image format (that is supported by IOS)

```
ImgView.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(_data) // _data contains of size 1350124
```

_data contains the byte array of image in RLE format. while is assign to ImgView.Image it gets

null. so image is not display on UIImageView.

how to make _data compatible format with UIImage

Comment: You will need to manually decode it and convert it to a supported format.  RLE is a general technique, not a concrete image format.  Can you view this image data using any sort of image viewer?  If you can then you should be able to determine what actual format it is in, and that will help you figure out how to convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after implementing RLE Algorithm just i code below few line of code long struggle finally I got it solution

```
Byte _imgData = GetRawData(_imgPath);  // this method get the byte array of size ([131072]) 

NSData _data = NSData.FromArray(_imgData);

ImgView.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(_data) 
int rawWidth = PixelData.ImageWidth;
int rawHeight = PixelData.ImageHeight;
float[] _rawSize = new float[rawWidth * rawHeight * 4];
for (int i =0; i < rawWidth * rawHeight; ++i) {
                _rawSize [4 * i] = (float)(1.0 / 255.0);
                _rawSize [4 * i + 1] = (float)(1.0 / 255.0);
                _rawSize [4 * i + 2] = (float)(1.0 / 255.0);
                _rawSize [4 * i + 3] = 255;
            }
int bitsPerComponant = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * rawWidth;


CGDataProvider _provider = new CGDataProvider (_imgData, 0, _imgData.Length);
CGColorSpace colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB ();

CGImage cg = new CGImage (
                rawWidth,
                rawHeight,
                bitsPerComponant,
                bitsPerPixel,
                bytesPerRow,
                colorSpace,
                CGBitmapFlags.ByteOrderDefault,
                _provider,
                null,
                true,
                CGColorRenderingIntent.Default
            );
ImgView.Image = UIImage.FromImage (cg);
```