# No exception in method call UIImage.LoadFromData(null)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

In IOS xamarin forms project:

```
UIImage.LoadFromData(null)
```

no exception

with

```
try { UIImage.LoadFromData(null); } catch {}
```

exception throw in catch block..

I need exception without try|catch

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: If you are not handling "global" exceptions elsewhere in your code, it is a `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` exception not matter how you code it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have a global exception handler, or you are calling that from a background thread and not awaiting the call to the async method so your exception is being swallowed. Example, just doing this:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    var x = UIImage.LoadFromData(null);
}
```

you will get a `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null` exception, but if you instead do:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    Task.Run(() => {
        var x = UIImage.LoadFromData(null);
    });
}
```

the exception will be swallowed and you will never see it, even if you have a global exception handler. [And this is by design.](https://codeopinion.com/handling-async-await-exceptions/) Any fire and forget task that is not `await`ed will swallow, i.e. not re-throw, any exceptions raised in the fire and forget task.

Awaiting the task will raise the exception:

```
public override async void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    await Task.Run(() => {
        var x = UIImage.LoadFromData(null);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are swallowing the exception. Add the exception you're expecting to the catch block

```
try
{
//code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//thrown exception
}
```

Comment: Where? I am using first block. Try catch version works fine, like your code. But I am using code without try catch and didnt see exception. Execution just skip something.

Comment: According to the answer to this question, if you set invalid value to the method you'll get null value returned. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959297/byte-array-shows-value-but-the-imgview-image-shows-null-in-ios